# Add points on zoom and remove points when zooming out

Tags: leaflet, layers, point, zoom, icon

**Problem**

I would like to add points/shelterIcons when zooming to level 12 or more and remove them again when zooming out. If all the points were defined as a layer I could add/remove them with the function down below. But the points are in GeoJSON files. I don't know how to "handpick" them and put them in a layer.

**Code**

```
//=======================
//Define map and map size
//=======================

var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [55.676098, 12.568337],
    zoom: 7,
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 18,
    zoomControl: false
});

L.control.zoom({
     position:'bottomright'
}).addTo(map);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);


//============
//Shelter icon
//============

var shelterIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/e/6/c/120743200840710503sleeping shelter white.svg.thumb.png',
    iconSize:     [20, 20], // size of the icon
    shadowSize:   [50, 64], // size of the shadow
    iconAnchor:   [0, 0], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
    popupAnchor:  [0, 0] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});

    //CENTERS VIEW WHEN USER CLICKS ON MARKER
function clickZoom(e) {
    map.setView(e.target.getLatLng(),map.getZoom());
};


//=============================
//Add GEOjson with feature info
//=============================

var RaslangenHalenRundt = L.geoJSON(RaslangenHalenRundt, {
      pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {icon: shelterIcon}).on('click', clickZoom);
  }, onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);

var Kalmarsundsleden = L.geoJSON(Kalmarsundsleden, {
      pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {icon: shelterIcon}).on('click', clickZoom);
  }, onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  var layerType = layer.feature.geometry.type;
  if (layerType == 'Point'){
    var PointPopupContent = feature.properties.name;
    layer.bindPopup(PointPopupContent);
  } else if (layerType == 'LineString') {
    var LinestringPopupContent = feature.properties.lengthdistance;
    layer.bindPopup("Route length: " + LinestringPopupContent + " km");
  } else {
    console.log('lengthdistance not present');
  }
}

    //WHEN USERS ZOOMS TO MORE THAN 12 THE SHELTERS APPEAR
map.on('zoomend', function() {
    if (map.getZoom() <12){
            map.removeLayer(shelterIcon);
    }
    else {
        //shelterMarkers.addTo(map);    
        map.addLayer(shelterIcon);
        }
});
```

Comment: Anyone with a suggestion? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use map.eachLayer() to find and remove specific Layers, but I think sectioning your geoJson into layer groups would be the cleanest since you are going to add and remove them repeatedly.

```
    var shelterPointsLayer = L.layerGroup();
    var everythingElse = L.layerGroup();

    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
      var layerType = layer.feature.geometry.type;
      if (layerType == 'Point'){
        layer.addTo(shelterPointsLayer);
      } else if (layerType == 'LineString') {
        layer.addTo(everythingElse);
      } else {
        console.log('lengthdistance not present');
      }
    }

    //Do not add your L.geoJson layers to the map. Add the layer groups instead
    everythingElse.addTo(map);
    //If your map starts at a zoom higher than 11 add the shelter points on map init
    shelterPointsLayer.addTo(map);

    //I changed the listener to 'zoom' so it will only fire on 12 or 11. This way it will only fire once when needed
    map.on('zoom', function() {
      if (map.getZoom() === 12){
        map.addLayer(shelterPointsLayer);
      }
    else if (map.getZoom() === 11){    
        map.removeLayer(shelterPointsLayer);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thx. You suggestions makes sense. When I try to implement your suggestion I get the following error (using Google's Developer Tools): "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLayer' of undefined" and it's pointing at `layer.addTo(everythingElse);`

Comment: @Saud hmm...I'm not sure what the issue is. I made a working fiddle here. Maybe it will help? https://jsfiddle.net/jm22/jeq8v2tu/17/

Comment: Got it working :) I had my L.geoJSON(...).addTo(map) at the beginning. Moved it after map.on('zoomend', ...) and it worked. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library I have made it for react js https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-linestring-editor. If you want I can create it for vanilla JS also.

install the library 
npm install leaflet-linestring-editor --save

Follow the example given in the link

Not able to add example over here due to some issues with JSX code issue in the editor provided over here

Comment: Hi and welcome to GIS.SE! Could you please provide a more detailed answer (code examples, etc.) instead of posting the link. This will provide a better context of the solution for the asking person.